# error in promises while trying to deploy my backend firebase functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise

I'm using firebase as my server and database for the first time and I'm trying to deploy my firebase backend functions to firebase I keep getting an error in my console about not nesting my promises:

> "error    Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return
>     52:16  warning  Avoid nesting promises                      promise/no-nesting
>     52:16  warning  Avoid nesting promises                      promise/no-nesting"

Any other way to write this promise?

```
let Promise = require('promise');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.addSimilarImages = 
functions.firestore.document('photos/{document}')

 .onCreate((snap, context) => {

       console.log('SNAP', snap)
       console.log('CONTEXT', context) 


by recreating a google storage style url called photoUrl
       const data = snap.data();
       console.log('DATA IN IS', data)
       const photoUrl = "gs://" + data.bucket + "/" + data.fullPath;
       conolse.log('url is', photoUrl);
 return Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => {
                //we put the photoUrl through the vison API and it returns a list of similar images 
               return visionClient.webDetection(photoUrl);

        })  //place these similar images in a array 
         .then(results => {
               console.log('VISION data all is: ', results)
               const webDetection = results[0].webDetection 

                 //update the document in the photos collection with the similarImages images 
               let similarImages = [];
               if (webDetection.visuallySimilarImages.length) {

webDetection.visuallySimilarImages.forEach(image => {
                               similarImages.push(image);
                       });
               }

                console.log('similarImages', similarImages)

db.collection('photos').doc(context.params.document).update({ 
similarImages })

         })
              .catch(err => console.log(err));
 }) 
   .then(res => console.log('pictures added'))
   .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did a good thing in the beginning :

```
    return visionClient.webDetection(photoUrl); //Returns a promise
})  //place these similar images in a array 
  .then( /* ... */ //Work on the promise
```

But in the end, in your promise, you just do

```
db.collection('photos').doc(context.params.document).update({ 
similarImages })
               .then(res => console.log('pictures added')) //Promise in promise
               .catch(err => console.log(err));//Promise in promise

         }) //End of promise
```

When you could do

```
    return db.collection('photos').doc(context.params.document).update({ 
similarImages })
   }) //End of promise
   .then(res => console.log('pictures added')) //Promise outside of promise
   .catch(err => console.log(err));//Promise outside of promise
```

Comment: It's always better to return something in a promise to control the execution flow. This is a "best practice" kind of thing. You don't __need__ to, if this is the last part of your call flow. You can just return nothing. If it's an error though, it's nice to re-throw it, so it can be handled elsewhere